# Search data in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I want to search data in database and put it in datatable but it seem my sql command its not correct because it didnt return any data. please help. thanks in advance. below is my code please check.

```
        protected DataTable SearchResident(String name, String ConnStr)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
            {
                con.Open();

                String SQL = "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, BirthDate, CivilStatus, " +
                    "Citizenship, MobileNo, Landline, PermanentAddress, Address FROM Residents " +
                    "WHERE FirstName LIKE '%name%' OR LastName LIKE '%name%'";

               using (cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(sdr);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I usually use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server and test my queries before adding the queries to my c# code.  SSMS is real easy to use and does a better job of finding errors in the query.

Comment: Or this : String SQL = string.Format("SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, BirthDate, CivilStatus, " +
                    "Citizenship, MobileNo, Landline, PermanentAddress, Address FROM Residents " +
                    "WHERE FirstName LIKE '%{0}%' OR LastName LIKE '%{0}%'", name);

Comment: you forgot to set SqlCommand

Comment: @Kushan thanks. but still didnt return anything

Comment: @jdweng thanks it's working but It's prone to sql injection if its not parametized.

Comment: Only if you are inserting into database.  Querying with select the data types are part of the query provided you don't cast the values to a different datatype.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a request to the `string SQL`, but you do not use it in your code. Example SQL-query:

```
class SQLQuery
{
    public static DataSet SQLGetData(string ConnectionString, string commandString)
    {            
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable("Table1");
        DS.Tables.Add(DT);

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {               
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
                //command.CommandTimeout = 3000;
                SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

                DS.Load(read, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, DS.Tables[0]);  
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }               
        }
        return DS;
    }
}
```

And get data:

```
private DataTable SearchData (string name)
{
    DataTabel dt = new DataTable();

    string connStr; // connection string
    string command = "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, BirthDate,"+
                     "CivilStatus, Citizenship, MobileNo, Landline, PermanentAddress,"+
                     "Address FROM Residents WHERE FirstName LIKE '" + name + 
                     "' OR LastName LIKE '" + name + "'";

    dt = SQLQuery.SQLGetData(connStr, command).Tables[0];
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: only thing about this is it's prone to sql injection

Comment: yes it prone to sql injection and you forgot the ''%" sign.

Answer (score 0):

you need a sql command, and to add name as a parameter :-

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
            {
                con.Open();

                String SQL = "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, BirthDate, CivilStatus, " +
                    "Citizenship, MobileNo, Landline, PermanentAddress, Address FROM Residents " +
                    "WHERE FirstName LIKE '%@name%' OR LastName LIKE '%@name%'";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Text);
                cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(sdr);
                }
            }
```

Comment: still didnt return anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this :

```
protected DataTable SearchResident(String name, String ConnStr)
{           
    try
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, BirthDate, CivilStatus, " +
                    "Citizenship, MobileNo, Landline, PermanentAddress, Address FROM Residents " +
                    "WHERE FirstName LIKE '%@name%' OR LastName LIKE '%@name%'";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

            sqlConn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            return  dt;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

One more suggestion, you are inviting SQL injection. Please use a parameterized stored procedure.

Comment: change yours to use parameters